# Find gateway of an interface

Tags: regex, linux, ubuntu, grep

For a bash integration, i need to retrieve the default gateway from an interface.

here is the output of the command route -n

```
Table de routage IP du noyau
Destination     Passerelle      Genmask         Indic Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         p.p.p.p         128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         x.x.x.x         0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.43.0.1       10.43.0.5       255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.43.0.5       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
y.y.y.y         x.x.x.x         255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
x.x.x.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
128.0.0.0       10.43.0.5       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
```

I try to capture gateway (Passerelle in French) for Iface tun0.

This regex is working on Rubular:

```
^[0\.]+\s+([\w\.]+)\s+.*UG.*tun0$
```

But this shell command doesn't work (no output):

```
route -n |egrep -oh '^[0\.]+\s+([\w\.]+)\s+.*UG.*tun0$'
```

Please, tell me why ?

Comment: There is no such thing as "default route for interface". Default route is route that is taken in case any other route in kernel routing table could not be used to tell the packet destination. In other words, there can be only one [default route or gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_gateway) for all interfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this (only one pipe) :

```
route -n | 
    awk -viface=eth0 '{if ($1 == "0.0.0.0" && $8 == iface) {print $2;exit}}'
```

or even better :

```
ip route |
    awk -viface=eth0 '{
        if ($1 == "default" && $2 == "via" && $5 == iface) {print $3; exit}
    }'
```

Comment: On my configuration, your even better solution doesn't work, because tun0 interface is a virtual interface created by OpenVPN, and it doesn't have a "default via" route. But it seems to me to be a better solution to retrieve the default gateway, without specifying any interface.

Comment: You have the choice now ;)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `awk`, rather than a grotesque regex?  Something like:

```
route -n | grep -e 'UG.*tun0' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested this, so there may be a typo...

Comment: Thx, i found the solution, i didn't know the existence of awk command :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option, without regex and awk:

```
route -n | grep -E "ppp0$" | tr -s ' ' | cut -f 2 -d ' '
```

Comment: @sputnick: Without regex to split the fields I meant. Also `grep ppp0` works also there